# Finding values of Limit

Tags: limits

Hi I have a question regarding finding the values of limit for the following equation.

The question states to find the values of the following limits:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{3}{1-\sqrt{x}}-\frac{3}{1-\sqrt[3]{x}}\right) $$

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x(t)=t^6$ is continuous at $t=1$, you can replace $x$ by $t^6$ to rewrite the problem as
$$
\lim_{t\to1} \bigg( \frac3{1-t^3}-\frac3{1-t^2} \bigg).
$$
Now it's easier to see how to combine the two fractions:
$$
\frac3{1-t^3}-\frac3{1-t^2} = \frac3{(1-t)(1+t+t^2)}-\frac3{(1-t)(1+t)} = \frac{-3t^2}{(1-t)(1+t)(1+t+t^2)},
$$
which diverges at $t=1$, the sign depending on which direction you approach $t$ from.

Comment: But when I sub t = 1 into the final equation i would still get  $\frac{3}{0}$. How do I solve the final equation? Thanks!

Comment: If the function were simply $3/(1-t)$ instead, how would you evaluate the limit?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the approach proposed by Greg Martin and set $x=t^6$, you can use Taylor expansion for each term and arrive, for the expression, to
$$\frac{1}{2 (t-1)}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{7 (t-1)}{24}+O\left((t-1)^2\right)$$ and arrive to the conclusions